# What is the proper way to perform pruning in Random Forest Regressor?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, grid-search, pruning

**Context of my problem:**

I'm performing hyperparameter tuning using GridSearchCV from scikit-learn in mt random forest regressor. To alleviate overfitting, I found that maybe I should use the pruning technique. I checked in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) and I found `ccp_alpha` parameter that refers to pruning; and I also found this [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_cost_complexity_pruning.html) that tells about pruning in the decision tree.

**My question:**

Since I'm looking for the best parameters of the random forest (GRidSeachCV), how should I input the `ccp_alpha` value? Should I include before or after the GridSearchCV? Considering that every time that I perform GridSearchCV the structure of the model changes... Are you guys have some reference? articles?

**My point of view:**

For me makes more sense to perform hyperparameter tuning first and then add the `ccp_alpha` (pruning) before train and test this "best model", but I'm not sure....

Comment: Pls notice that SO is about *specific coding* questions; non-coding questions about machine learning theory & methodology are off-topic here, and should be posted at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) instead. Notice the **NOTE** in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info). Also, pls **re-read** [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for SO.

Comment: That said, the answer below is **correct**, i.e. if you are to experiment with different `ccp_alpha` values, you should make them part of your CV procedure - after all, it *is* a hyperparameter (notice that the original RF algorithm was proposed with unpruned trees). Your primary objective is a low test MSE/MAE, *not* to avoid overfitting (plus there's always the danger of *underfitting*).

Answer (score 4):

Since `ccp_alpha` is also a parameter to tune, it should be a part of your CV. Your other parameters depend on that too.

It is a regularization parameter (like `lambda` in Lasso/Ridge regression) thus a high value gives you very small trees.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @CutePoison!! But I was thinking that using ccp_alpha as parameter, the best model will always be the one with the smallest value of ccp_alpha. To confirm it I tried many times and I verify it. But using the smallest ccp_alpha I get the best estimation but also the model continues to overfit...If I increase the ccp_alpha the overfit reduces, but the result got a little bit worse. So maybe the best approach is to tune without ccp_alpha parameter, given the possibility to get deep trees, and then prune after that, instead of prune and tune at the same time,but I'm not sure

Comment: Your training error would of course be lowest with the smallest value - is it your validation error?

Comment: My validation error follows the behavior of the test set....So, with small values of ccap_alpha, I got small value for MAE metric for train set and high values of MAE for validation and test set.

Comment: Is it a classification/regression task? And what is your error-value exactly?

Comment: It's a regression task. With the default model, "ccp_alpha = 0" I got MAE for train set = 0.52 and for test set MAE =1.55. Increasing the ccp_alpha to 0.05 I can achieve MAE for train set = 1.19 and for test set MAE = 1.6...If I increase ccp_alpha even more, I will reduce the difference between train and test, of course, but eventually, I'm gonna get worse results in test set as well because the model tends to be more "conservative"

Comment: As I wrote in the description of my question, I believe that considering this is a pos-pruning approach I should tune the hyperparameter first, not considering the ccp_alpha...Then, I use ccp_alpha to prune my "best model".....I'm just not sure if this is right :x